# Proof of $\left| \operatorname{cn}\left( x(1+ i) \mid m \right)\right|=1$ for $m=\frac{1}{2}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: special-functions, elliptic-functions

Let $\operatorname{cn}(u\mid m)$ be Gudermann's notation for the [Jacobi elliptic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions) $\operatorname{cn}$. It is well known to be doubly periodic. For $0<m<1$ the two periods, $4 K(m)$ and $4 i K(1-m)$, are purely real and purely imaginary respectively. For any $n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$:
$$
    \operatorname{cn}\left(u + 4 n_1 K(m) + 4 n_2 i K(1-m) \mid m \right) = \operatorname{cn}\left(u \mid m \right)
$$
and where $K(m)$ denotes the [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) (in that link $m=k^2$).

For $m=\frac{1}{2}$, $f(x,y) = \operatorname{cn}(x+i y \mid m)$ is doubly periodic in a square with sidelength $4K\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \approx 7.4163$.

By looking at [Peirce quincuncial projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce_quincuncial_projection) I noticed empirically that, for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x,x)$ is of unit magnitude:
$$
    \left| f(x,x) \right| = \left| \operatorname{cn}\left(x+i x \mid \frac{1}{2}\right) \right| = 1
$$
[image]

I am looking for either a proof, or a reference to one.

Thank you.

Comment: Interesting, I've been playing around with [Peirce's projection](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RWBQE.jpg) a lot lately...

Comment: @J.M. Perhaps you could clear some of my confusion [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24257/peirces-quincuncial-projection).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Jacobi's imaginary transformation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobisImaginaryTransformation.html)
$$ \mathrm{cn}(iu|m)=\frac{1}{\mathrm{cn}(u|m')},$$
and parity of $\mathrm{cn}(u)$ will do the job. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly it. I will post my solution shortly

Comment: Yours is quite a lot neater!

Answer (score 5):

Using the addition theorem:
$$
   \operatorname{cn}\left(x+ i x \mid m\right) = \frac{\operatorname{cn}(x \mid m) \operatorname{cn}(i x \mid m) - \operatorname{sn}(x \mid m) \operatorname{sn}(i x \mid m) \operatorname{dn}(x \mid m) \operatorname{dn}(i x \mid m) }{1-m \operatorname{sn}^2(x \mid m) \operatorname{sn}^2(i x \mid m)}
$$
Using the Jacobi's imaginary transformations:
$$
   \operatorname{cn}(i x \mid m) = \frac{1}{\operatorname{cn}(x \mid 1-m)} \quad 
    \operatorname{sn}(i x \mid m) = i \frac{\operatorname{sn}(x \mid 1-m)}{\operatorname{cn}(x \mid 1-m)} \quad 
  \operatorname{dn}(i x \mid m) =  \frac{\operatorname{dn}(x \mid 1-m)}{\operatorname{cn}(x \mid 1-m)}
$$
we get
$$
  \operatorname{cn}\left(x+ i x \mid m\right) = \frac{\operatorname{cn}(x \mid 1-m) \operatorname{cn}(x\mid m)-i \operatorname{dn}(x \mid 1-m) \operatorname{dn}(x\mid m) \operatorname{sn}(x\mid 1-m) \operatorname{sn}(x \mid m)}{\operatorname{cn}^2(x\mid 1-m) + m \operatorname{sn}^2(x \mid 1-m) \operatorname{sn}^2(x \mid m)}
$$
Substituting $m={1 \over 2}$ we get
$$
  \operatorname{cn}\left(x+ i x \mid {1 \over 2}\right) = \frac{\operatorname{cn}^2(x\mid {1\over 2}) - i \operatorname{sn}^2(x\mid {1\over 2}) \operatorname{dn}^2(x\mid {1\over 2}) }{\operatorname{cn}^2(x\mid {1\over 2}) + {1\over 2} \operatorname{sn}^4(x\mid {1\over 2})}
$$
The absolute value now follows to be 1:
$$
 \left| \operatorname{cn}\left(x+ i x \mid {1 \over 2}\right) \right|^2 = \frac{\operatorname{cn}^4(x\mid {1\over 2}) + \operatorname{sn}^4(x\mid {1\over 2}) \operatorname{dn}^4(x\mid {1\over 2}) }{\left( \operatorname{cn}^2(x\mid {1\over 2}) + {1\over 2} \operatorname{sn}^4(x\mid {1\over 2}) \right)^2}
$$
Using defining relations $\operatorname{cn}^2(x \mid 1/2) + \operatorname{sn}^2(x \mid 1/2) = 1$ and $\operatorname{dn}^2(x \mid 1/2) + {1 \over 2} \operatorname{sn}^2(x \mid 1/2) = 1$ the right hand side equals one.